# JavaScript: Truncating text based on outer object's dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I want to, using JavaScript, chop the given text to fit the object in which the text resides and add "..." at the end.

For example:
JavaScript got data from 3rd party web service and needs to put the text into 200 x 300 px div. Text's length vary, so let's say it will take much more space than provided.

How to determine at which point text will break through the border and prevent that by chopping text and adding "..." at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [several jQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/ellipsis) that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using the canvas element, it can be used to measure the width of the text. Here's an example:

http://uupaa-js-spinoff.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/uupaa-excanvas.js/demo/8_2_canvas_measureText.html

Answer (score 1):

ruzee.com [has a solution](http://www.ruzee.com/blog/2007/08/ellipsis-or-truncate-with-dots-via-javascript) that uses `prototype.js` and a small bit of code [MIT licensed] to do what you want; [demo](http://www.ruzee.com/files/ellipsis/test.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look into the CSS 3 property `text-overflow` which also does this.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-text-20010517/#text-overflow-props

It's possible to check if the browser supports it, so you always can add a JavaScript fall back.

```
if (!'textOverflow' in document.createElement('div').style) {
   // Use JavaScript solution here
}
```